# Is there anyway to get rid of a folder but go to the subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to have my website go from

```
www.example.com/folder/subfolder
```

to

```
www.example.com/subfolder
```

What I have only seems to redirect me to

```
www.exmaple.com/folder/

Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\www.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /folder/%1/$1 [L]
```

---- UPDATE ----

These are the current rewrite rules.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^((?!folder/).*)$ /folder/$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: I just updated my .htaccess file and this didn't work. When I go to www.example.com/subfolder I get a 500 Error.

Comment: Are there existing rules there? If yes please post them here.

Comment: I updated my question to include all the items in my htaccess file.

Comment: Do you want to force HTTPS also? Are you using some CMS/PHP framework also?

Comment: I am forcing HTTPS and yes I am. Though I am making the PHP framework myself. I just have never messed with .htaccess files.

Comment: Now I get just a 404 Error when I try to go to   www.example.com/subfolder

Comment: There is no rule to handle that. If you enter `/folder/subfolder/abcd`  it will load content of `/subfolder/abcd`

Comment: I have `/folder/subfolder/index.php`  I want to go to just `/subfolder/index.php` and have it load, but it's not loading.

Comment: That worked but not the way I would have liked it to.
I was hoping it would be just take out the `/folder/` part all together but I guess that wont happen.